# Using jQuery to change the CSS of the entire wordpress website

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I've looked around and can't find a simple way around this problem. I've created a custom word press theme (my first time) and it's working nicely. I've got it hookedup to a simple jQuery file which plays a short animation when the page is loaded and changes the CSS and does some additional animations when certain buttons are pressed. It's a simple day/night theme that works well. I call the file in my header.php. However everytime an internal hyperlink is pressed (eg. any page of the website) it loads the entire jQuery file again and also resets the CSS to it's original form. To be clear, I need the user to click on something on the home page which will change the CSS of the page. This is working. However, I need this to remain in place throughout every page on the website.

Is there a simple solution to this? I really don't want to use cookies/sessionID or some of the other complicated 'solutions' I've seen. I'm not that technically capable.

Cheers.

Comment: This question might be better suited for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a hash? in the window.location object you can set a hash to something like www.mysite.com/page#night then www.mysite.com/page#day then when the DOM has loaded, check against the window.location.hash property to see if its set to day or night or nothing then default to something.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp

example:

http://jsfiddle.net/QV6xa/1/

JSfiddle doesn't allow me to change the url but if you copy/paste this example some where else it should work.